# Why can't I graph my summation equation for calculating perfect squares (The equation is correct, I tested it)

Tags: square-numbers

This is the equation and graph on Desmos.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: You say you want to graph your equation (implying you can't), but then you provide two screenshots of the graph of said equation... leading me to ask: what do you mean by "graphing"?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @H.sapiensrex By "graphing", I mean that the values in the graph don't fit the values that are plugged into the function. You can plug numbers like 1, 2, 3 ... in the fuction and it will give you the square of these numbers. However, the output that appear in graphed function in desmos differ from the outputs when I plugged inside the function. eg. (instead of 4, it gave me 6)

Comment: You are plotting the function $$n\mapsto\sum_{k=0}^{n}(2n+1)=(n+1)(2n+1)$$ instead of $$n\mapsto\sum_{k=0}^{n}(2k+1)=(n+1)^2.$$

Comment: Is should be $2k+1$ not $2n+1$.

Comment: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/9hqxzvrpqb